# iOS: indexPathForItemAtPoint when cell is not selected

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

In my app I want to know what's the indexpath of cell that I touch and I use this:

```
CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:grid_element]; 
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [grid_element indexPathForItemAtPoint:location];
int index = selectedIndexPath.row;
```

It work fine but the problem is when I touch another space where there isn't a item, the result of index is ever 0.
Is it possible to check if I don't touch inside an item? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`index` is 0 because `selectedIndexPath` is nil. You should be writing

```
CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:grid_element]; 
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [grid_element indexPathForItemAtPoint:location];
if (selectedIndexPath != nil)
{
    NSInteger index = selectedIndexPath.row;
}
```

P.S. Sorry for previous (incorrect) answer, I misunderstood.